# how do i sort an array of objects via the comparable interface?

Tags: java, comparable

EDIT: I am trying to sort the array objects by their "calories".

currently I am working on an assignment, where one of the tasks is to output a sorted array.

As far as I understand, my failure to sort my array could be solved via the comparable interface. Then it would be possible to sort my array using the java.util.Arrays.sort(/*var to be sorted here*/) method.

I know I could simply write another loop, but that is not what I am trying to achieve. Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Food implements Comparable<Food> 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = 5;
        Food f1 = new Food(TYPES[1], 300); 
        Food f2 = new Food(TYPES[2], 400);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(createSortedRandomList(n)));
        System.out.println("f1 calories: " + f1.getCalories());
        System.out.println("f1 type: " + f1.getType());
        System.out.println("f2 calories: " + f2.getCalories());
        System.out.println("f2 type: " + f2.getType());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(f1.compareTo(f2));

    }

    private static final String[] TYPES = {"Apple", "Pear", "Cookie"};
    private String type;
    private int calories;

    public Food(String type, int calories)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.calories = calories;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        String foodString = "Type:" + getType() + " Calories:" + getCalories();
        return foodString;
    }



    public String getType() 
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getCalories() 
    {
       return calories;
    }

    public static Food[] createSortedRandomList(int n) 
    {

        Food[] food = new Food[n];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            food[i] = new Food(TYPES[(int)(3.0*Math.random())], (int)(501 * Math.random())); // 0 <= calories <= 500
        }

        Arrays.sort(calories); // incorrect code here **************************************************************
        return food;

        // TODO: create a list with n random instances and sort them
    }

    public int compareTo(Food o) 
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (this.type.length()*this.calories < o.type.length()*this.calories)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        else
        {
            return 1;
        }

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class implementing `Comparable` means it has a "natural" sort mechanism.

The one you have defined for your `Food` class is very strange, based on the product of the length of the type and the calories.

What I think you need are some external comparators, each comparing a different aspect of your class.

A `public static class CaloriesComparator implements Comparator<Food>` can compare only based on the calories (and then it can compare by the food type).

You can then create a `TypeComparator implements Comparator<Food>` that first compares the type, and only if the types are equal compares the calories.

You can then use it in the `Arrays.sort(<array>, <comparator instance>)` sort method.

Using Java 8, you can write the comparators even simpler:
`Comparator<Food> comparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(Food::getCalories).thenComparing(Food::getType);`

Comment: The strange sort mechanism is actually specified in the task, so I think that means that the criteria in the CompareTo method are actually the criteria by which the array should be sorted.

in which case, I just have to figure out why my sorted array is giving me incorrect output. Example output:

[Type:Cookie Calories:378, Type:Cookie Calories:178, Type:Pear Calories:231, Type:Pear Calories:209, Type:Pear Calories:467]

Comment: I went back through the compareTo method and realized I had an error. Before posting this question I did not know that the compareTo method was the one which was actually doing the sorting. Your explanation helped me to understand what was required in my task.

Answer (score 0):

Your compareTo method hassome typo errors.
Always use Override annotation to be sure you override the correct method.
I improved your toString method to see comparison is working correctly.

public class Food implements Comparable
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n = 5;
    Food f1 = new Food(TYPES[1], 300); 
    Food f2 = new Food(TYPES[2], 400);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(createSortedRandomList(n)));
}

private static final String[] TYPES = {"Apple", "Pear", "Cookie"};
private String type;
private int calories;

public Food(String type, int calories)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.calories = calories;
}


public String toString()
{
    String foodString = "Type:" + getType() + " Calories:" + getCalories()+ "\n";
    return foodString;
}



public String getType() 
{
    return type;
}

public int getCalories() 
{
   return calories;
}

public static Food[] createSortedRandomList(int n) 
{

    Food[] food = new Food[n];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        food[i] = new Food(TYPES[(int)(3.0*Math.random())], (int)(501 * Math.random())); // 0 <= calories <= 500
    }

    Arrays.sort(food);

    return food;

    // TODO: create a list with n random instances and sort them
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Food o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return 0;
    }else if (this.calories < o.calories) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.calories == o.calories) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}